Please unlock and reopen "How do I link a cell in Google Spreadsheets to a cell in another document?"
In March 2023, a moderator closed the 2010 question "How do I link a cell in Google Spreadsheets to a cell in another document?” under "needs details or clarity."
The moderator also locked the question as "historically significant" and left the following comment:

This question was posted during the private beta of this site. It was closed because it doesn't meet the current quality standards and locked for historical reasons as nowadays it looks to be a trivial question.

The post is locked for "historical significance," therefore the community is unable to cast reopen votes or flag the question. Only a mod or CM can reopen the question, which is why I needed to create this meta post.
The community values this question
This 14-year-old question has been extremely well received by the community:

It's been viewed 663K times.
It was upvoted every year (2010-2023).
It only ever received one downvote (2018).
It has a combined score of +203.
It has multiple highly voted answers, with the top one having a score of +210, followed by others with +36, +10, +4, +2, +1...
For more than a decade, no single flag for closure was raised by any community member, as evidenced by the question's timeline.

The question should be reopened and unlocked
It's unclear what specifically prompted the closure and locking, but the question meets our current site standards. If the closure and locking were related to the community’s recent "research" meta discussion in September 2023, that's already been resolved by the community in favor of not closing questions for a lack of research.†
Given this community consensus and our established site policy, I believe the closure and locking of this question were unwarranted.
I respectfully request that the moderators reopen and unlock "How do I link a cell in Google Spreadsheets to a cell in another document?" to align with our site policy and community consensus.

† More info on the research discussion at Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?

The argument for reopening the question is compelling.
I have performed the following actions:

Removed the lock.
Made some edits for clarity.
Submitted the post to the reopen review queue for the community to vote on. 


